# How can I expose Querable API using OData for EF Core Keyless Entity(Database view)?

Tags: rest, odata, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I am using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/7.3.0 to expose OData 4 based Querable API using ASP.NET Core 3.1 API

I have EF Data context with keyless entity(Database view), When I try to expose it with OData Convention based model

```
   modelBuilder
   .Entity<Student>(eb =>
    {
        eb.HasNoKey();
        eb.ToView("vw_students", "public");
    });
```

And here is my OData EDM Model mapping with EF Core entity type

```
var edmBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
edmBuilder.EntitySet<Student>("Students");       
return edmBuilder.GetEdmModel();
```

*I get an error on this line edmBuilder.GetEdmModel() The entity set 'Students' is based on type 'ODataCore31.Student' that has no keys defined.*

My questions-
1) Are Keyless entity types are natively supported by OData model?
2) Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 7):

To expose a *Keyless* View or custom query via OData you must use an Unbound Function instead of a full OData Controller, which is configured via the `EntitySet<T>()` expression in the conventional builder.

This makes sense because an EntitySet *Controller* allows item based operations but without a specific *Key* there is no conventional way to address a specific *Item* as its own Resource.

> A keyless type is therefore a `ComplexType` and not an `Entity`, by definition an *Entity* **MUST** have a key so that OData can support *by item* or *key based* navigation.

The OData way to expose a *Keyless* collection as an *Unbound Function* involves 3 important steps:

### 1. Declare your query in a controller so that it returns an `IQueryable<T>`

A specific quirk about an *Unbound* Function or Action is that they are not specifically bound to *any* controller, so you can declare your unbound endpoints in any controller of your choosing.

> I prefer to create a specific controller to host all unbound components, the name is not important as long as it does not clash with other controllers or entity types in your domain.

As with the default collection endpoints, we need to make sure our endpoint returns an `IQueryable<Student>`, you can still use the `IActionResult` response type if you need that level of abstraction, but the implementation should be queryable.

### 2. Set the specific route for the method using `ODataAttributeRouting`.

This is a crucial element, in *usual* convention-based implementations we do not declare specific routes on each method, each controller's route prefix is resolved from the controller name and the endpoints are resolved from the method names.

> It helps to follow conventions as much as possible to keep your implementation transparent and configurable, if you always declare specific routes then it is important that the routes you configure match the registration with the `ODataConventionModelBuilder`.

In the specific case for an *unbound* endpoint, there is no controller element in the route at all, which has two implications: you cannot use a route prefix specified at the controller level because leaving the prefix empty in an `ODataRouteComponent` will trigger the default logic which will use the name of the controller class; and you **must** declare the route on the endpoint itself as a full route because all the convention based routing depends on the controller element in the route to map to the controller to resolve the possible endpoints, so the runtime won't know which controller to inspect.

> You can write your own route resolution logic but that is out of scope for this issue.

This is a minimal example controller implementation:
***NOTE:** `"odata"` is the *routePrefix* registered to the OData service in this example*

```
[ODataAttributeRouting]
public partial class ViewsController : ODataController
{
    protected AppDbContext _db;
    public ViewsController(AppDbContext context)
    {
        _db = context;
    }

    [HttpGet("odata/" + nameof(Students))]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Student> Students(ODataQueryOptions<Student> _queryOptions)
    {
        return this._db.Students;
    }
}
```

### 3. Register/Map the route in the `ODataConventionModelBuilder`

This step is often overlooked, if you skip this step the endpoint can be queried via HTTP but this is a standard *Web API* implementation and not a conventional OData implementation, so the endpoint will not be documented in the CSDL (*$metadata*) or some *swagger* implementations and as a result will not be available to OData client generators.

```
var edmBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
edmBuilder.Function("Students").ReturnsCollection<Student>();     
return edmBuilder.GetEdmModel();
```

An inline services registration would look like this, *notice the `"odata"` routePrefix declared in the `AddRouteComponents` method, this **MUST** match the custom route declaration prefix.*

```
services.AddControllers().AddOData(opt =>
{
    var edmBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    edmBuilder.Function("Students").ReturnsCollection<Student>();   

    opt.AddRouteComponents("odata", edmBuilder.GetEdmModel()).EnableQueryFeatures();
}
```

---

*This solution was tested and written using OData 8.0 (for .Net 5.0), the concepts are fully compatible with OP's requested `ASP.NET Core 3.1` and OData Lib v7.3 however some of the namespaces are different. 7.3 can easily be upgraded to 8 or 9 and I encourage you to do so as there are significant performance and functional improvements in the latest releases.*

Answer (score 0):

It looks like keyless entities are explicitly unsupported in OData's Edm Model Builder:
https://github.com/OData/ModelBuilder/blob/86d26d7346e9359e64e5ec08c31ac7e829cbe788/src/Microsoft.OData.ModelBuilder/ODataModelBuilder.cs#L629

So the answer to your first question is no, for the time being.

For the second question, this may not be possible in your use case, but if your keyless entity corresponds to a view on your database, you could actually just build a normal (not keyless) entity if there's a column or combination of columns on this view that's unique. In one of my models, I created an entity class corresponding to a database view, and then added the [Key] attribute to the property on a column on that view that's guaranteed to be unique per record. Then OData treats this just like any other entity. The only caveat here is that it's read-only.

If, on the other hand, you want to surface a keyless entity to OData because it pulls columns from multiple database tables/views (like you could do with a [defining query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/advanced/defining-query) in classic EF), and you don't want to create a new view in your database, I think you're out of luck.